# Cloud function / no arguments defined / Stripe Login link creation / flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

As a front dev trying to understand Cloud functions, I would like to get a login link for my Stripe Connected users (using Oauth Stripe V2, They register and get an AccountId, I would like to pass this Account Id to Stripe to let them connect to their dashboard) I don t understand why my arguments are not passing through the following nodeJs function / it returns :

```
loginLink: Error: Stripe: Argument "account" must be a string, but got: undefined (on API request to `POST /accounts/{account}/login_links`)





exports.loginLink = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const accountId = req.query.id;
  console.log('this is accountId ---->' + accountId);
  const loginLink = await stripe.accounts.createLoginLink(
  accountId
  );
  console.log(req.query.id)
  return loginLink;
})
```

And called in Dart / Flutter as follow

```
Future<void> getUrl() async {
    HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('loginLink');
    dynamic results = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
    'id': 'acct_***********',});
    print (results.data);
    String urlLink = results.data;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `accountId` in the `loginLink` cloud function from:

```js
    const accountId = req.query.id;
```

to:

```js
    const accountId = req.body.id
```

Explanation:
`req.query` "is an object containing a property for each query string parameter in the route" while `req.body` "contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body"

[Source](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req)